# Dealing with large arrays as Redux states

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, state

Imagine you have a huge array of items as a part of your redux state. Now every time an item is added/deleted I want to make some API call. Currently I am doing something like this :

```
 class Mixer extends React.Component{

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     // compare two massive arrays
     // API call
   }

   render() {
     //whaeva
   }
 }


 MixerContainer = connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   mapDispatchToProps
 )(Mixer)
```

which compares two big arrays (nextProps vs current props) and makes an API call if a new item was added or if an item was deleted. This seems very inefficient however, is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: How big is the array? perhaps you can separate the arrays and implement the logic in separate reducers?

Comment: Well it's not very big at the moment, but for the sake of the argument let's say it's thousands of items. Not sure what you mean by implementing logic in separate reducers, could you give an example?

Comment: So suppose have API call that gets many posts and each post contains many comments. You can then store the blogs and comments in a separate property in the store. But I guess the real issue here is how to compare 2 potentially massive arrays. Perhaps you can use a Map to keep track of the store's property (which becomes the prop in your Mixer component).

Comment: I would suggest you to have an API call at the place where you are adding or deleting an item, to avoid comparing arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always do those things in actions. Create an action in which you invoke the API call and after the server returns success, change the client store. By this, you prevent unwanted situations where client and server data sets are different. Server should always be your source of truth.

Comment: I was considering this too. I would really like the API call to be "reactive"  to the state however and not rely on the action.

Comment: I don't see any problem in calling API in the action. Comparing two huge arrays seems to be a bad idea for the performance of your app. How do you compare them?

Comment: I might end up doing this, I just think it's not very React way. As in, in future there might be other ways to set the state, other than through 'add' or 'delete' actions. This means I will have to do the API call in every one of those actions. I'd much rather prefer the behaviour reacting to state if this is possible to do in a performant way. I'll wait for other answers and then will accept.

Comment: You don't have to copy the logic, just do an action in this way `updateArray('remove', content)` and then adjust the call according to the parameter. Depends on what is your logic over the arrays.

Comment: btw. I think the server should be your source of truth. Because if you delete some item from the array on the client side, but the API call will fail for some reason, you will have a problem...that's why you should always do it in the actions and then after success update the client store.

Comment: @JaroslavMálek That's a good point. Can you update your answer with your comments and I will accept. Thank you.